# How to return multiple tiffs as http response?

Tags: c#

I have tiffs stored in database, a search by DIN can return one or many tiffs. I am creating this endpoint that will return tiffs, below my code I only get the first page. My idea is: database returns byte array of each page, combining these arrays will produce a byte arrays that contains all pages and pass that to response. Any idea why this returning only the first page?

```
byte[] imagesArray = new byte[0];
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    image = row["Image_blob"];
    imagesArray = addArrays(imagesArray, image)
}

response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ImagesArray);
return response;



static byte[] addArrays(byte[] arrayA, byte[] arrayB)
    {
        byte[] outputBytes = new byte[arrayA.Length + arrayB.Length];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(arrayA, 0, outputBytes, 0, arrayA.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(arrayB, 0, outputBytes, arrayA.Length, arrayB.Length);
        return outputBytes;
    }
```

Comment: Well... `Images = addArrays(image)` replaces whatever was stored in `Images` previously

Comment: what is 'Images'? what is 'addArrays(image)'? there is not enough information to understand where something is going wrong

Comment: How is `addArrays` defined?

Comment: consider looking at `multipart` responses.

Comment: what is multipart responses?

Comment: addArrays is working code that I got from here.

Comment: ImagesArray is being re-assigned every time the loop runs. Please post the code for "addArrays"...someone will be able to help you but there is not enough of the code posted here.

Comment: I inspected the final result array and I can see that it has all pages. somehow this has to do with frame being lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you concatenate tiff files together in a "file" and then read it as TIFF you will only see the first file. The TIFF header at the beginning of the first TIFF only describes the content of the first image. Data beyond the first TIFF will be ignored. You need to ether send the TIFF files as multi parts of the response. (Google http multipart response) In this case you will be sending several "files". Or you need to construct one TIFF file which contains all the images. I'm not sure how you do this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF#Multiple_subfiles implies you need to add to the first tiff header all the other pages as sub images.